# correos con laravel, enviando multiples correos desde un string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, email

tengo un inconveniente, el cual no e podido solucionar, en un proyecto tengo una base de datos en la cual en una columna le agrego correos entonces se vería algo así `columna emails a@correocliete1.com, b@correocliente1` y en otro cliente puede solo tener un correo en esa columna. 
y en otro puede tener tres correos o mas,  algo así `columna emails a@co1.com, b@co1.com, c@co1, d@co1.com` de esta manera yo ocupo enviar a tres clientes supongamos digamos ocupo enviar los correos a `co1 y al correocliente1` en conjunto a todos los correos que poseen en la base de datos.  lo que hago es lo siguiente recorro en un foreach la tabla de correos y lo pongo en inputs. pero un input sale con los correos `a,b,c` de esa manera pero quisiera agarrar ese string y separarlo en inputs individuales

```
    <div id="menu2" style="display: block; width: 90%; height: 110%; opacity: 1; float: left;">  
<br>
<form class="form-group" method="POST"  name="formNombre" action="/mail" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      @csrf
     <div class="clientes">
        <div class="titulo">
          Plantilla de correo  
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="func" value="ActualizarCliente">
        <input type="hidden" id="cliente-id" name="cliente-id" value="62">
        <div>
        <label style="position: absolute; left: 9.5%; top: 18%;">Asunto Correo:</label>  
          <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Titulo de correo" required="required" size="50" style="position: absolute; left: 19%; top: 18%;"> 
         </div>
          <input type='text' style="position: absolute; left: 72.5%; top: 24%;" placeholder="Quincena" name="calendary" required="required" class="datepicker" id='datetimepicker4' />

          <button type="submit" class="btnAgregar posisionA" value="enviar correo">Enviar correo</button>


          <div style="position: absolute; left: 10%; top: 24%">
             <b>Seleccione una plantilla: </b>
            <select required="required" id="plantilla"  onchange="SelecionPlantilla(this.value)" >
              <option value="">Seleccione una plantilla</option>
              @foreach($plantillas as $plan)

              <option class="last"  id="{{$plan->ID}}" value="{{$plan->ID}}">{{$plan->plantilla}}</option>

              @endforeach
            </select>
           <input type="button" name="Mostrar" id="Mostrar" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"  value="Mostrar">
          </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 10%; top: 29%; ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <textarea  class="ckeditor" name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                             <div class="tabla{{$plan->ID}}" id="archivos" style="display: none;" >
                             <p id="plant{{$plan-ID}}" >

                               <p id="descrip">{{$plan->description}}</p>

                             </p>
                             </div>                             
                      </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div style="position:  absolute; left: 9.1%; top: 12%;" >
               <select name="year">
                 <option value="">Año a enviar opcional</option>
                 <option value="2019">2019</option>
                 <option value="2020">2020</option>
                 <option value="2021">2021</option>
                 <option value="2022">2022</option>
                 <option value="2023">2023</option>
                 <option value="2024">2024</option>
                 <option value="2025">2025</option>
                 <option value="2026">2026</option>
                 <option value="2027">2027</option>
                 <option value="2028">2028</option>
                 <option value="2029">2029</option>
                 <option value="2030">2030</option>
                 <option value="2031">2031</option>
                 <option value="2032">2032</option>
                 <option value="2033">2033</option>
                 <option value="2034">2034</option>
                 <option value="2035">2035</option>
                 <option value="2036">2036</option>
                 <option value="2037">2037</option>
                 <option value="2038">2038</option>
                 <option value="2039">2039</option>
                 <option value="2040">2040</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div style=" position: absolute; left: 26%; top: 12%;">
              <select name="fecha">
                <option value="">Mes a enviar opcional</option>
                <option  value="0">Enero</option>
                <option  value="1">Frebreo</option>
                <option value="2">Marzo</option>
                <option value="3">Abril</option>
                <option value="4">Mayo</option>
                <option value="5">Junio</option>
                <option value="6">Julio</option>
                <option value="7">Agosto</option>
                <option value="8">Septiembre</option>
                <option value="9">Octubre</option>
                <option value="10">Noviembre</option>
                <option value="11">Diciembre</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <a href="/Admin/clientgroup/genera"><button type="button" class="btnAgregar posisionB" >Regresar</button></a>
            <div class="noenviarEmail">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sinEmail" value="SI" >No enviar correo
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 10%; top: 89%">
            <input type="checkbox" name="machote" id="machote" value="SI">Guardar como machote?
              <input type="text"  hidden="hidden" name="plantillas"   id="plantillas">
              @foreach($clients as $clien)
               @foreach($grupoCliente as $gc)
                 @if($gc->groupid == $Grupo)
                  @if($gc->cliente == $clien->id)

                     <input  id="correosUser"  name="Emails[]" value="{{$clien->email}}" class="correousuario">
                     <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="idclientes[]" value="{{$clien->id}}">

                  @endif 
                 @endif
               @endforeach
              @endforeach

              @foreach($grupo as $gr)
              @if($gr->id == $Grupo)
              <b>Grupo selecionado: </b>
              <b><strong><output  >{{$gr->name}} : </output></strong></b>
              <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="grupos" value="{{$gr->name}}">
              <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="idgrupo" value="{{$gr->id}}">
              @endif
              @endforeach

              @foreach($archivos as $arc)
              @foreach($idboletin as $ars)
              @if($arc->id == $ars)
              <output>{{$arc->name}}</output>
              <input type="text" id="arch" hidden="hidden"  name="nombre" value="{{$arc->name}}">
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="adjunto[]" hidden="hidden" id="adjuntos" value="{{$arc->link}}">
              <br>
              <input  type="text" id="fecha" hidden="hidden" name="calendario" value="{{$arc->fecha}}">
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="tipo[]" hidden="hidden"  value="{{$arc->tipo}}">
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="idarchivo" hidden="hidden" value="{{$arc->id}}">
              <br>
              @endif
              @endforeach
              @endforeach
            <hr>
            </div>

       </div>
</div>
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          language: "cr",
          autoclose: true
      });
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ActivadorEditor(){
    $('#editor1').wysihtml5();
  };
  ActivadorEditor();
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var SelecionPlantilla = function(a){
   document.getElementById('plantillas').value = a;
  }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
   .posisionB{
      position: absolute; left: 70%; top: 17%;
   }
   .posisionA{
     position: absolute;
     left: 60%;
     top: 17%;
   }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Mostrar').click(function(){
        var id = $('#plantilla').val();
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        $.ajax({
            url : '/clientgroup/text',
            data : { ID : id ,_method: 'POST',_token:token},
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(json) {
              console.log(json)
              if (json.length ==0) {
                $('#archivos').hide();
                swal('Buscamos pero','Encontramos informacion','info');

              }
              $('#archivos').show();
                json.forEach(function(element) { 
                   swal('','','success');  
                   CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(element[0]);
                });
            },
            error : function(xhr, status) {
                swal('Error','Disculpe presentamos algún errro','error');
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

        var year; 
    $("#previous-year-calendar").click(function(){
        year = $("#year").text();
        if(year >= '2020'){    
        $(".year-order-"+year).hide();
        year--;

        $("#year").text(year);

        $(".year-order-"+year).show();
       }
    }) ;

    $("#next-year-calendar").click(function(){
        year = $("#year").text();

        $(".year-order-"+year).hide();
        year++;

        $("#year").text(year);

        $(".year-order-"+year).show();
    }) ;



</script>
<!--SWAL() alerts-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

</div>
@endsection
```

si ven en la parte de Emails del input que es traido por un foreach sale de esta manera el nombre `name='Emails[]'`
como logro seprar los strings que viene en desde la base de datos y que se creen los inputs individuales a cada correo.

en la parte del controlador lo tengo de esta manera

```
$subject = $request->input('subject');
    $e_mail = $request->input('Emails');  
    $estipulo = $request->input('plantillas');
  $text = $request->input('editor1');
  $files = $request->input('adjunto');
  foreach ($e_mail as $key) {
        Mail::send('emails.envia',array(
           'key'   =>  $key,
           'subject' => $subject,
           'text'    =>  $text,
           'estipulo'    =>  $estipulo,
           'files'  =>  $files,
        ),
        function($msj)use($key,$estipulo,$text,$subject,$files){
          $msj->subject($subject);
          $msj->to($key);
          if($files) {
            foreach ($files as $attachment) {
              $msj->attach(public_path('/storage/boletines/').$attachment, [
                          'as' => $attachment,
                          'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                  ]);    
            }
          }
        });
  }
  return Redirect::to('/Admin/reportes/create');
```

de esta manera se veria en la pantalla como se muestran los correos pero http://prntscr.com/nfwi4e  en este caso solo son un correo por cliente cada input es un correo de clientes pero ese cliente en un input puede salir asi los correos a,b,c,d en un solo input. como se podria recorrer ese input para que se hagan varios inputs a  luego b  luego c del mismo cliente.

Comment: php tiene un funcion llamada [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) que,crea un array a partir de un string dandole un caracter como separador.

Comment: ok si, puedo usarla desde la vista el explode()

Comment: en esta parte @foreach($clients as $clien)
               foreach($grupoCliente as $gc)
                 if($gc->groupid == $Grupo)
                  if($gc->cliente == $clien->id)
                        
                     <input  id="correosUser"  name="Emails[]" value="{{$clien->email}}" class="correousuario">
                     <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="idclientes[]" value="{{$clien->id}}">
                   
                  endif 
                 endif
               endforeach
              endforeach

Comment: es que en el controlador no funciona poner ese explode()

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nfwi4e     asi se ve con correos de varios clientes estos solo tiene puesto un correo cada cliente pero ocupo ponerles varios correos a los clientes y de esa manera enviarle los correos digamos que en los campos salen varios correos a,b,c y esos son los correos de los clientes pero salen en un solo input o que se pueda enviar con eso sabiendo que son correos idividiuales o creando los inputs por cada separacion de coma

Comment: si tienes `$clien->email` que es  "a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com" `@php
$emails = explode("," $clien->email); @endphp` esto retornara un arreglo.. que puedes usar en un foreach!

Comment: esto en la vista.

Comment: es donde recibes de la base de datos cierto?? si quieres usarlo en el contralador  `$request->input('Emails')[0]` o puedes eliminar los [] en el input para que venga solo `$mails = explode(",",$request->input('Emails'));` por ello te deje el link al manual de explode

Comment: osea en el request del input solo pongo [0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
foreach ($e_mail as $mail) {
    // eliminamos los espacios al inicio y al final del string
    // creamos una arreglo a partir del texto separado por comas.
    $emails_ = explode(",", trim($mail));
    // recorremos el arreglo
    foreach ($emails_ as $key) {
        Mail::send('emails.envia',array(
           'key'   =>  $key,
           'subject' => $subject,
           'text'    =>  $text,
           'estipulo'    =>  $estipulo,
           'files'  =>  $files,
        ),
        function($msj)use($key,$estipulo,$text,$subject,$files){
          $msj->subject($subject);
          $msj->to($key);
          if($files) {
            foreach ($files as $attachment) {
              $msj->attach(public_path('/storage/boletines/').$attachment, [
                          'as' => $attachment,
                          'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                  ]);    
            }
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: eso quitando los [] del input de emails o se deja como esta el input

Comment: no ya con esto te funcionara si quieres cambiarlo en el `frontend` ya tu decides si lo quires pero tendrias que eliminar el primer foreach de este loop! ya que al eliminar los `[]` el `$request->input('Emails');` pasa a ser una varible y no un arreglo!

Comment: me sale este error cuando recorre el email del input con dos correos. Address in mailbox given [ richardsrr0105@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.  mira http://prntscr.com/nfyjs6

Comment: dale al inspector estos es stackoverflow necesito ver el codigo!

Comment: no, ya encontre por que tiraba ese error era por otra cosa. lo que me mostraste funciono correctamente muchas Gracias